# Clicking Cancel on Date/Timer react-native-community/datetimepicker throws an error

Tags: react-native

Upon clicking on `cancel` or the opacity background on `<DateTimePicker />`, throws an error.

is there a callback to `cancel` ?

i dont see anything about `cancel` in react-native-community/datetimepicker docs

react-native-community/datetimepicker : **3.4.3**

date-fns : **2.19.0**

here's my code

```js
  function NewAppointmentScreen () {
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date(Date.now()));
    const [showCalendar, setShowCalendar] = useState(false);
  
    const onChangeDate = (e, selectedDate) => {
      setShowCalendar(false);
      setDate(selectedDate);
    };
    
    const onPressCalendar = () => {
      setShowCalendar(true);
    }
    return {
      <View style={styles.container}>
        //callback 
        <View style={{ width: '48%' }}>
            <CustomInput
              editable={false}
              title="Date"
              value={format(date, 'MM/dd/yyyy')}
              leftIcon={
                <Icon
                  color={THEME.PRIMARY}
                  name="calendar"
                  type={ICON.MaterialCommunityIcons}
                />
              }
              onPressIcon={onPressCalendar}
            />
          </View>
      
          {showCalendar && (
          <DateTimePicker
            display="default"
            mode={'date'}
            style={styles.datePicker}
            value={date}
            onChange={onChangeDate}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the error message ?

Answer (score -1):

If anyone finds this question, you should check if the value is valid before setting the state:

```
const onChangeDate = (e, selectedDate) => {
  setShowCalendar(false);
  selectedDate && setDate(selectedDate);
};
```

Comment: This answer helps me in the case of setShowCalendar refresh state of screen and consequently the calendar re-open instantly.